# It is possible to add a run time object to physical object repository file?

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I'm working on UFT 11.53, Windows 8.1 Pro and vbscripts.

**My problem :** I've an application in which I've to automate tests and qualifications. I would like to add an new object (using vbscript) to my repository object.

**Questions :**

- *It is possible to add a run time object to physical object repository file ?*
- *If yes, how do this using vbscript ?*

Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [programmatically add object to qtp local repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30164977/programmatically-add-object-to-qtp-local-repository)

Comment: Actually I think it's a duplicate of something else: [How to add objects to object repository automatically using vb scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14827603/3848). Which in my opinion doesn't have a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Please view this linked-in thread https://www.linkedin.com/grp/post/1079537-262719920